# Is it possible to report a user who is continuously posting unnecessary comments?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently looked at some new questions and I found a user posting rude comments.
Isn't it possible to throw that person out of this site?

The user has been doing it continuously.

How to make a request to get his comments checked and account deleted if necessary?
We don't want peace breakers.right?

Comment: Flag comments as rude. If the same user has enough, they'll get talked to by a diamond mod

Comment: ^ And be sure so! Post examples here please to justify.

Comment: Guys.I am new here.I am sorry if this question sounded stupid.I was just trying to help.
Thanks for all that down vote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ .I didn't get you.
What examples?

Comment: @Patrice
How to flag it as rude?

Comment: And we've been giving advice how to improve.

Comment: Hover your mouse on the comment. A flag icon will appear to the left. Click that and take it from there.

Comment: Okay.Got it!
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @Bart I'm not sure, do they have enough rep?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yup, the flag by the comment! And don't worry about downvotes on meta, they don't count against your rep :).

Comment: @Patrice
Thanks again.
I didn't know this.

Comment: @MathewsMathai no problem. This is what most people don't realize coming to meta :P. It's also why downvotes come quicker on meta ;)

Comment: Yeah.Sounds legit. :)

Comment: @Patrice - Is there some threshold of flagged comments that raises a moderator flag? Where is this documented?

Comment: @MartinSmith it's been mentioned multiple times by diamond mods on meta when someone brought up similar questions. As the rest of how stack works, the exact number is not known

Comment: I wasn't asking for the exact number. Just something official that states that this is the case.

Comment: @MartinSmith possible it exists. I have no clue. I base myself off diamond mods comments, so it may not be easy to hunt these down

Comment: @MathewsMathai _".I didn't get you. What examples? "_ Concrete links for such comments of course dude!

Answer (score 6):

As you don't seem to be willing to share an example of such rude comment we can only redirect you to the [be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) where I copy the part, "Don't be a jerk".

> - Name-calling. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
> - Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
> - Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.
> - Harassment and bullying. If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page.

From [Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) the topic about comment flagging:

- hover over the offending comment and click the small flag icon that appears.
- specify a reason:

  - rude or offensive
  - not constructive / off-topic
  - obsolete
  - too chatty

Do notice that a lot of regular users use pre-canned/auto comments to quickly address issues they spot in new questions. Those comments are not tailored to be friendly (but shouldn't be rude!), they are made to get the Original Poster (OP) to fix their posts.

Comment: Well, the better auto-comments do try to avoid any rudeness beyond that inherent to using an impersonal canned response....

Comment: @NathanTuggy true, I added that nuance. Due the lack of examples I felt I needed to add the existence of the auto-comments and their often factual and to the point message that might be considered harsh to new users. It would help if we get feedback on those. The auto-comments used by the SOCVR chat room are published [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments). Drop a message in the room if you think we need to improve on those.

Comment: Oh!Thanks for that piece of info guys!!

Comment: I'll have to look for an example.It's not too easy to find.The last one was deleted by the moderator.
Some 'Comp' named user had posted it.
@rene

Answer (score 4):

> How to make a request to get his comments checked and account deleted if necessary? We don't want peace breakers.right?

As mentioned in the comments to your question you can flag for a moderator - especially if you think it's an ongoing problem. When flagging the comment use the "other" reason and explain this (put a link to this meta post for instance). However, believe it or not, we're also fairly good at recognising the same name coming up again and again.

Moderators have access to user data (stuff you might not be aware of etc..) so we can make a reasoned judgement on whether just a few comment deletions (maybe the user has a great history, but got up on the wrong side of the bed today?) or a reach out to a user (or more) is necessary.

So - flag appropriately if you're concerned and it'll be looked in to.

Comment: Yes.I'll take care of that!